# Elastic search result with range operator returning wrong results

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

Elastic search result with range operator returning wrong results

[image]

ElasticSerchQuery

```
{"query": {"bool": {"filter": [{"term": {"Id": {"value": "v1"}}},{"term": {"Segment": {"value": 1}}},     {"term": {"Attribute": {"value": "Test"}}},{"range": {"Value_Min": {"lte": 999999996}}},{"range": {"Value_Max": {"gte": 999999996}}}]}}, "sort": [{"Value_Min": {"order": "asc"}}], "size": 10}
```

First two column in the table is exact match and 3rd and 4th column in the table is range operation
The datatype used for the range operation() value min and value max is float.
I am searching for large value(999999996) when I search for small values it returns the correct value.

Did the search query dependent on the data type for range operator?

I am expecting one row in the result and which is the 2nd row of the table mentioned here.
but I am getting all the rows when searching from the elastic search head

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to floating-point precision.

You need to change your `Value_Min` and `Value_Max` fields to be of type `double` instead of `float` and your query will work out the way you expect.